# Allow access to PhpMyadmin only on a specified virtualhost

Tags: apache-2.2, php, virtualhost

I'm working on a multiple virtualhost Environment. I've installed PhpMyadmin for Mysql Remote Control.

Environment is configurate as below:

```
one.domain.com
two.domain.com
onlyphpmyadmin.domain.com
```

Now, if i accesso to one of the three domains

```
http://one.domain.com/phpmyadmin/
http://two.domein.com/phpmyadmin/
http://onlyphpmyadmin.domain.com/phpmyadmin/
```

the result is the same, the access to Phpmyadmin is allowed.

The goal is to obtain a situation like this one below

```
http://one.domain.com/phpmyadmin/ --> access denied
http://two.domein.com/phpmyadmin/ --> access denied 
http://onlyphpmyadmin.domain.com/phpmyadmin/ -->access allowed
```

whith no hack similar to

```
<?php 
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'onlyphpmyadmin.domain.com')
die('access denied');

 ...
 ?>
```

on some Phpmyadmin file.

---

Here my Phpmyadmin configuration file

```
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin

<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
        AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

        php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
        php_flag track_vars On
        php_flag register_globals Off
        php_admin_flag allow_url_fopen Off
        php_value include_path .
        php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp
        php_admin_value open_basedir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/
    </IfModule>

</Directory>

# Authorize for setup
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup>
    <IfModule mod_authn_file.c>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "phpMyAdmin Setup"
    AuthUserFile /etc/phpmyadmin/htpasswd.setup
    </IfModule>
    Require valid-user
</Directory>

# Disallow web access to directories that don't need it
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup/lib>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Remove the Alias declaration

```
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
```

from the server context and put it in the relevant vhost context

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName onlyphpmyadmin.domain.com
    .
    .
    .
    Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
</VirtualHost>
```

It may be easier and preferable to just include the whole phpmyadmin config into the relevant vhost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName onlyphpmyadmin.domain.com
    .
    .
    .
    include /path/to/phpmyadmin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

and then remove that include from the server context and restart apache for the changes to take affect.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me on Centos 6.5. I tried both methods and still able to access it from all domains.

Comment: Remember to restart Apache2 after change its configuration and to eventually add a new CNAME to DNS config

Answer (score 3):

In RHEL/CentOS, Apache loads /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf to set up the /phpmyadmin alias. The Directory directive is also initially set to only allow traffic from localhost, so you may receive a 403 error when accessing phpmyadmin like "domain.com/phpmyadmin".

Using the following, you can set up RHEL/CentOS to only allow the /phpmyadmin alias to work from a specific virtual host.

/etc/httpd/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf

```
<Directory "/usr/share/phpmyadmin">
#  Order Deny,Allow
#  Deny from all
   Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>

#Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
#Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
#Alias /mysqladmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
```

Next, add the alias directive to your vhost and restart Apache.

Please note, this is not the most secure implementation. Please take care to secure /phpmyadmin through authentication, IP restrictions or a combination of both.